# How to update a table triggered by a VIEW change in postgres

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers

In postgres, I have a joint VIEW on two tables. One of those tables has a timestamp column, the other one doesn't (We cannot change this!).

Now I want the timestamp column be updated, whenever the other table gets UPDATEd. I thought a Trigger on the VIEW would be feasable. But this doesn't work as expected, because i don't update the VIEW, but the TABLE. Please consider this minimal example:

```
create table test(i int, update_ts timestamp);
create table test_2(i int, s text);
create view test_view as select t.i, t2.s, update_ts from test t left join test_2 t2 on t2.i = t.i;

insert into test values(1, now());
insert into test values(2, now());
insert into test_2 values(1, 'one');
insert into test_2 values(2, 'two');

select * from test_view;
-- all is fine

update test_2 set s = 'foo' where i = 2;

select * from test_view;
-- colums s is fine, but how to trigger a refresh of the update_ts column of id 2?
```

It is NOT possible to create an UPDATE Trigger on test_2 in my scenario, because the whole table gets updated due to an old nasty import mechanism. This would lead to an update of id 1, too, which isn't intended.
It is also NOT possible to add a timestamp column to test_2 and load the MAX value of both in test_view (which would be a nice solution in deed).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is add `s text` to table `test` and at end of the import process insert/update table `test` with new and changed values from `test_2`.

Answer (score 0):

The following trigger function and trigger definition will update `update_ts` in `test` whenever column `s` in the corresponding row in `test_2` is changed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_ts_on_change_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
  UPDATE test
    SET update_ts = now()
    WHERE test.i IN (SELECT new_rows.i
                       FROM new_rows
                       JOIN old_rows
                         ON new_rows.i = old_rows.i AND new_rows.s IS DISTINCT FROM old_rows.s);

  RETURN NULL;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_ts_on_change
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON test_2
  REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_rows
              OLD TABLE AS old_rows
  FOR STATEMENT
  EXECUTE FUNCTION update_ts_on_change_func();
```

Multiple columns can be checked for changes by `OR`ing them in the join condition in the trigger function; e.g.:

```
ON new_rows.i = old_rows.i AND
   (new_rows.s IS DISTINCT FROM old_rows.s OR
    new_rows.t IS DISTINCT FROM old_rows.t OR
    new_rows.u IS DISTINCT FROM old_rows.u)
```

This approach only updates rows in the `test` that correspond to changed rows in `test_2`. All other rows in `test` retain their values.